# Change root-path for bash auto-completition (TAB) feature

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Can I force BASH to see certain folder (let's call it **main_folder**) as the root of my file-system? I need BASH to behave this way at least during auto-completion of parameter names and command names, while inside the folder.
Let's say that I have directory tree that looks like this:

```
/z/y/main_folder/a.txt
/z/y/main_folder/bin/b.txt
/z/y/main_folder/bin/c.txt
/z/y/main_folder/bin/d.sh
```

Now that I call this custom version of bash, I could simply type:

```
/> /bi(TAB)/(TAB)  /a(TAB)
```

What would expand to:

```
/> /bin/d.sh /a.txt
```

Where `d.sh` is command to be run and `a.txt` is it's first parameter. If I was CDed into `/bin/` I could do:

```
/bin/> ./(TAB) (TAB)(TAB)
```

What would expand the command `d.sh`, and would give three options for the first parameter (namely: `b.txt`, `c.txt`, `d.sh`).

Few brief additional points:

- I do not care if the original root of the file-system is inaccessible or is accessible via hard/soft link.
- I do not care if I am able to run any commands that are out of scope for **main_folder** (I will change the `$PATH` variable anyway) or any shell builtins.
- I do not care what the `$PS#`, `$PWD`, etc. variables actually hold.
- I do not want to make my own version of BASH (changing source-code). My application should (probably) be started via some script (*sh*) or program (*C/C++/C#*) that setups the environment and either continues in interactive mode or runs interactive shell on one of it's last lines.
- I want to run this as an unprivileged user. I do not want to allow the user to `chroot`.
- I am not concerned with security, and I am not intending to jail anyone. I simply need BASH to auto-complete.
- I would not mind to 'trap' BASH during directory lookups.

I have a feeling that `set`, `compgen`, `complete` and `compopt` builtins are what I need to utilize, but I do not know how. It does not seem that the examples I have found about these commands show all the features, and man pages are quite chaotic.

Thanks, Kupto :)

Comment: Why does `d.sh` require its arguments to be these pseudo-paths?

Comment: `d.sh` would be interface routine for program that manages my `/Documents/Projects` folder. I have a program that allows me to manage this entire sub-directory tree, and now I want to create an interactive front-end to it. I do not want to program the shell on my own, so I rather want to rape BASH to do it for me. The auto-completion is the only thing I do not know hot to do.

Comment: to clarify... `d.sh` would be something like: `make_new_project`, `info_about_project` or `list_projects`